# How to customize the controlbox of a winform in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controlbox

I want to customize the controlbox of my winform with a different background for it and different button images. How can I do so? Is there any way to make a custom controlbox with usercontrol or something like that and then add it to the winform?

Comment: I strongly suggest you look at WPF. It has much bigger customization features than winforms.

Answer (score 1):

You have no influence on that using .NET framework means. You'd have to implement custom drawing for the non-client area of the form. The following might help you here: http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=CustomerBorderForm&title=Painting%20NonClient%20Area

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom controls by inheriting from a `UserControl` like so

```
class MyControl : System.Windows.Forms.Button //this could also have been System.Windows.Forms.UserControl or any other existing control type as a template
{
    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Paint whatever you wish on this buttons graphics using e.Graphics
    }
}
```

There is a lot to programming custom controls. To much to answer here. A good reference is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t.aspx

You could create your own sort of Forms control and hide the parents controlbox.
Or maybe you can inherit from `System.Windows.Form` and createa a custom form. But I have never tried that myself.

And for using OnPaint you have to keep some rules in mind if you care about performance and/or flickering and such: [What is the right way to use OnPaint in .Net applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652568/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-onpaint-in-net-applications/13652570#13652570)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understand correct. Do you want create your own control?
If is, try this:

- Create a Custom Control.
- Alter the type of your control.

Change:

```
public partial class MyCustomControl : Control { ... }
```

For:

```
public partial class MyCustomControl : Form { ... }
```

- Alter the value of Controlbox properties to false.
- Alter any properties you want customize.
- Create a new Form.
- Alter the type of your form.

Change:

```
   public partial class MyForm : Form { ... }
```

For:

```
public partial class MyForm : MyCustomControl { ... }
```

And now your MyForm it's like your MyCustomControl and you can reuse in all your project.