# Change the border color of textbox in c# winforms - Newbie

Tags: c#, winforms

I did write a code for border color change for label but the same does not work for textbox.

This is the code

```
    label1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.label1_Paint);


    void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, label1.DisplayRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        }
```

For textbox how to change the border color?

Comment: In the duplicate question, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39420512/3110834) is what you are looking for. The strange thing is that the accepted answer with 4 votes is totally misleading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating your own textBox using the UserControl. Here is a sample that will get you started:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    private string text;

    public string Text

    {
        get { return textBox.Text; }

        set { textBox.Text = value; }
    }

    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

    public UserControl1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(UserControl1_Paint);

        this.Resize += new EventHandler(UserControl1_Resize);

        textBox.Multiline = true;

        textBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

        this.Controls.Add(textBox);
    }

    private void UserControl1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        textBox.Size = new Size(this.Width - 3, this.Height - 2);

        textBox.Location = new Point(2, 1);
    }

    private void UserControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)

    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `TextBox` does not have a `Paint` event handler.  Because of that, you cannot modify things like the Border Color.  You can, like with most controls, alter the `BackColor` and `ForeColor`, and you can input a `BackgroundImage`.  Maybe get a little creative with that and layer things to give the appearance of a `BorderColor`.

A `Panel` does, however, have a `Paint` Event Handler.  You can do it, essentially, the same way you did you `label`, but with a some different arguments:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, panel1.Bounds, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Place a `Panel` on the form. Set properties `AutoSize = true` and `AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink`.

Place your `TextBox` on this `Panel`. Set properties `Location = new Point(2, 2)` (choose your own coordinates) and `BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None`.

Create a `Paint` event handler for this panel. Draw the desired border.