# How to stop Windows from painting TextBox directly by Windows

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, custom-controls

I tried to change the look of WinForms custom TextBox by overriding OnPaint or/and WndProc method. But in both cases before my method is invoked Windows already draws basic TextBox.
[What's draw here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CZqB.jpg)

And what my method does, it's drawing on top of it.

So do you know any solution to this problem ?

Documentation says that it could be unachievable (link below:)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/constituent-controls

```
public class TestTextBox : TextBox
{
    public TestTextBox() : base ()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Blue),10,10,70,10);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        // base.OnPaintBackground(pevent);
        pevent.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red),10,10,90,10);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
        {
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.BlueViolet), 10, 10, 70, 10);
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }

    private void InitializeComponents()
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Black;
        this.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want the functionality of a textbox and a custom drawn control, I'd recommend creating a CustomControl with an invisible textbox. Use the textbox internally for whatever you want to do and have the [CustomControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/developing-custom-windows-forms-controls) do the painting.

Comment: The customization is limited, take a look at [TextBox BorderColor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39420512/3110834) for example.

Comment: @Fildor what about for example: SelectionStart, Multiline, CharacterCasing properties ? I think just invoking the  textbox internally won't do the job :/

Comment: Well, that's what you got. Take the standard, roll your own _or_ go and find some Control-Collection that meets your requirements (something like DevExpress, ... but some of them are not free).

Comment: @Fildor the main problem is that my CadCustomTextBox implement a plenty of overrider behavior e.g. when we have more text, and I trying to figure out, the easiest way to change it's look, without loosing the functionality or redeploying it on created screens :/