# Is there a way to paint a colored border around a Textbox?

Tags: c#, textbox, visual-studio-2013, border, windows-forms-designer

I want to create a colored border around a TextBox on a Windows Form, something like what can be done in Android (with the "ID" and "PackSize" EditText widgets):

[image]

Is this possible (without writing a gazillion LOC and sacrificing a chicken)?

There is a BorderStyle property, but that does not change the color of the border. The ForeColor and BackColor properties also do nothing helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768938/change-the-bordercolor-of-the-textbox

Comment: Three words: W P F.  Customizing basic Winforms controls has never been easy or recommended.  In WPF, it's a breeze.

Comment: It's an old question but I believe here is the [correct way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39420512/3110834) of doing what you were looking for. Also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38405319/3110834) may be useful for change border color on focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either:

1. Put the textbox in a slightly larger Panel with a dark `BackColor` or
2. Handle the `Paint` event and draw the border yourself.

Comment: 2. : The TextBox doesn't have a Paint event, so it would have to be the Form's. Not a big problem, just worth mentioning.