# How to change TextBox border color and Style while typing?

Tags: c#, textbox, border

I'm writing a C# programming which has couple of textboxes which give some information from the user. I have a "Submit" button to save the entered information.
 I want this textbox work like this:
A. When there is no information entered, by pressing the Submit button, a thick red border shown around the textbox.
B. when the user is been noticed, and try to enter some information in the corresponding textbox, after a certain number of letters (for example after entering at least 4 letters), the border style of the textbox will be switched to the regular style!

I will be appreciated if you could help me! 
I searched a lot for TextBox border color but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: what kind of an application is this? windows forms, wpf, web??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: try this https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+textbox+border+color

Comment: This is very much like [c# - Change the borderColor of the TextBox - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768938/change-the-bordercolor-of-the-textbox) and [How to change TextBox border color in C# ?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ab0521e0-d81a-40ac-bb84-d5873331ed6f/how-to-change-textbox-border-color-in-c-?forum=csharpgeneral) and [[Solved] How to change Textbox BorderColor in C#? - CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/95669/how-to-change-textbox-bordercolor-in-c).

Comment: Also note that this is actually two questions; (1) How to change TextBox border color and (2) while typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, whenever you ask something in SO, you have to put some effort and show what you´ve tried so that people will be willing to help you. Take that as a note for future questions.

Having said that, you have to add a handler to the TextChanged event of your TextBox control. Then you have to change the properties as you desire:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //PUT THE BUSINESS LOGIC IN HERE
    if(textBox1.Text = "")
    {
                textBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red);
                Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                int variance = 3;
                g.DrawRectangle(p, new Rectangle(textBox1.Location.X - variance, textBox1.Location.Y - variance, textBox1.Width + variance, textBox1.Height +variance ));
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work because it will not even compile. Plus, how do you know the OP is using windows forms?