# How to set the margins of text box red if error is present

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I was just wondering if its was easily possible to set the margins of a textbox a particular color? Im using `winforms` and in my validating event handlers i have a series of `error providers`, which if return false I want to set just the margins red and if successful green. is this possible with out having a any controls hidden behind ? I know how to set the foreground and panel colour but it just seems so sloppy to have to have this all hidden behind it. this is my validating event handler.

```
       private void txt_LndLine_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {

            if (utility.isNum,(txt_LndLine.Text))
            {
                epLandline.SetError(txt_LndLine, "Please use unknown Entity!!!");

                return;
            }

            else 
            {
                epLandline.Clear();
                _IsValid = true;

            } 
        }
```

Just a query, as the event hadnler works fine just wouldn't mind a smarter way of presenting the errors rather than the icon

Comment: There is a good answer for changing border color in this SO, slightly different, but I think nicer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768938/change-the-bordercolor-of-the-textbox.  See the answer by Reza Aghaei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution, which won't add any extra controls. It paints the border onto the `TextBoxes`' `Parent`.

Set it up by hooking the routine into the `Paint` event  of your `TextBox`'s `Parent` once, maybe like this:

```
textBox1.Parent.Paint += DrawMargins;
```

Now you can set the `Tag` to hold the `Brush` you want to use:

```
textBox1.Tag = Brushes.Red;
textBox2.Tag = Brushes.Green;
```

After changing the `Brush` you need to trigger the routine,  by `Invalidating` the `Parent`:

```
textBox1.Parent.Invalidate();
```

To take one `TextBox` out of the painting reset the `Tag` to `null`:

```
textBox1.Tag = null;
```

You can also un-hook the whole event of course:

```
textBox1.Parent.Paint -= DrawMargins;
```

Here is the drawing method:

```
private void DrawMargins(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Control parent = sender as Control;
    foreach ( Control ctl in parent.Controls)
    { 
        SolidBrush brush = ctl.Tag as SolidBrush;
        if (brush == null) continue;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, ctl.Left - ctl.Margin.Left,
            ctl.Top - ctl.Margin.Top,
            ctl.Width + ctl.Margin.Horizontal,
            ctl.Height + ctl.Margin.Vertical);
    }
}
```

Note that this will  work for any control which has a `SolidBrush` in the `Tag` and is a child of the **same** parent. If some controls as nested, say in a `Panel` or a GroupBox, I guees you should replace the loop over the `parent.Controls` collection by a `List<Control>` of the participating controls..

[image]

I have enlarged the left margin of the 1st `TextBox`, as you can see..

Answer (score 0):

May be the answer in comments is a good one (@RudyTheHunter).

I have a simple way of doing.

Put a `panel` control right below the `text box` and change the border color of the panel.

I tried it and looks as shown in below image.

**Code:**

```
            if (utility.isNum,(txt_LndLine.Text))
            {
                epLandline.SetError(txt_LndLine, "Please use unknown Entity!!!");
              //PANEL COLOR
              this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
              this.panel1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);

                return;
            }

            else 
            {
                epLandline.Clear();

               //PANEL COLOR
                this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                this.panel1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);

                _IsValid = true;    
            }
```

[image]