# NumericUpDown that only allows a range of values of the power of two

Tags: vb.net, winforms, numericupdown

I have a NumericUpDown whose minimum value is set to 1 and its maximum is 64. I have to increment it, from 1 to 64, using the values of the power of 2, so it must be `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64`.

I've tried several ways to change the NUD increment but with no satisfying results.
How could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reduce the size of the text portion of the NumericUpDown control so it is not visible, you can put a read-only TextBox right next to it so it looks like it is part of it, then...

```
Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged
    Dim nud = DirectCast(sender, NumericUpDown)
    tbForNud1.Text = (2 ^ nud.Value).ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    tbForNud1.ReadOnly = True
    tbForNud1.Text = "1"
End Sub
```

You might want to change the colour of the border of the TextBox: [Change the borderColor of the TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768938/change-the-bordercolor-of-the-textbox/38405319).

Comment: I'd go with [Jimi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66798146/1115360) if this is for anything more than a one-off.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a Custom Control derived from NumericUpDown, so you can handle internally the value changed events that are generated by different possible actions: click the Up/Down Buttons, spin the MouseWheel, enter a number manually, data bindings etc.

The [OnValueChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.onvaluechanged) method override has the last word: if a value submitted doesn't meet the criteria (being a power of two in the specified range), the number is changed to the nearest (higher) valid value.

The [OnMouseWheel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.updownbase.onmousewheel) override just calls the corresponding method based on the positive or negative value of the Delta.

<sub>► Requires `Option Infer On` or small changes</sub>

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Forms

<DesignerCategory("Code")>
Public Class NumericUpDownPow2
    Inherits NumericUpDown

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Maximum = 64
        Me.Minimum = 1
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub UpButton()
        Value = Math.Min(Value * 2, Maximum)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub DownButton()
        Value = Math.Max((Value / 2), Minimum)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseWheel(e As MouseEventArgs)
        Call If(e.Delta > 0, Sub() UpButton(), Sub() DownButton())
        DirectCast(e, HandledMouseEventArgs).Handled = True
        MyBase.OnMouseWheel(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnValueChanged(e As EventArgs)
        Dim nearest = CDec(Math.Round(2 ^ Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(Value, 2))))
        Value = Math.Max(Math.Min(nearest, Maximum), Minimum)
        MyBase.OnValueChanged(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```