# WinForms Element messes up vertical text alignment after border removal

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, alignment, border

I have a Control that ultimately inherits from `TextBox`

If I don't remove the border then the text vertical alignment is fine:

[image: Aligned with border]

But I want to remove the border like this:

```
public partial class MyReadonlyDataField : TextBox
{
  private void InitializeComponent()
  {      
    this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;      
    this.Appearance.BorderAlpha = Infragistics.Win.Alpha.Transparent;
    this.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
    this.Height = 19;
  }
}
```

But then the text alignment is off. How can I fix that?

[image: Missaligned without border]

Comment: Why not keep the border but make its color transparent?

Comment: I just tried to do that, but it keeps showing up. Strange

Comment: The problem is that I can't just set the border color for a textbox so easily: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768938/change-the-bordercolor-of-the-textbox

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. If I set the perfect height for my `TextBox` control then the text will be centered, because the control has the exact height that matches the text font.

To achieve that I set the **hidden** `AutoSize` property of `TextBox`. It can't be set in the Forms-Designer nor does IntelliSense list it as property. But it exists and works when set to `true`!

Comment: You can set the `Margin` property of Controls to compensate: defines the external distance (from the Container)

Comment: But I would have to set that individually every time depending on the height of the control. I find it a bit better to let the control take care of that automatically.

Comment: You said you have a Custom Control there. So, when you set the BorderSyle to none, you can automatically compensate. I cannot say whether the Infragistic's TextBox also derives from TextBoxBase, but the AutoSize feature of the TextBox changes its Height, which may have other consequences. Anyway, of course you do whatever you're more comfortable with.