# How Can Draw Line Over Other Controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a UserControl which inherited from Windows.Form.Panel but, I added some properties to make UserControl have border property as shown in following image:

[image]

Question:

1. If user set dock property of inside (child) control to fill, it will place on all area of panel and border will disappear. This problem has been solved by setting padding option equal to border thickness.
2. If AutoScroll property of panel set to true, vertical and horizontal scrollbar place on edge of then panel and right and bottom border will disappear again. How can solve this problem?

thank you all

Comment: You need to customize the size and appearance of the non-client area. You need to handle [`WM_NCCALCSIZE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccalcsize?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to change the size of the nonclient area, and handle [`WM_NCPAINT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-ncpaint?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)to paint on the nonclient area. Look at the example here: [Custom border width and border color for UserControl or Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76540368/3110834)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a UserControl with a border that has child controls with scrolling.

1. Create UserControl Padding(10,10,10,10) BackColor(Red)
2. Add Panel DockStyle(Fill) AutoScroll(True)
3. Add Child Controls to Panel
   [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x9yN.png)